# why the file size changes while converting csv to xlsx in perl

Tags: perl

Quick question..

why the file size changes while converting csv to xlsx in perl?

For instance, while converting 1 MB csv file to xlsx, it is generating 6 MB of xlxs file
and while converting 6 MB csv file to xlsx, it is generating 1 MB of xls file.

How come this situation happens as there is no logical difference.? Any clue?

Comment: Please use internationally recognised `SI` unit of `MB` if you mean megabytes https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte else "1 mb" looks like "1 millibit". Thank you.

Comment: Sure, point noted..Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two formats are substantially different. The XLSX also needs to store the formatting of the cells and many other things - in fact, you can explore the contents if you change the extension to `.zip` and unzip the file. The CSV stores just the values and separators (and possibly quotes and escapes), so it's much smaller.